# Question about required rigour for basic elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am wondering if anyone can help to tell me if my methods for solutions to the problems from by book are correct, and if not please help me to get on the right path.

First,  prove that $$A \cap ( B \cup C )= ( A \cap B ) \cup ( A \cap C)$$

My attempt:

Let $x \in A \cap ( B \cup C)$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in B \cup C$

then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ or $C$

so $x \in A$ and $B$ or $x \in A$ and $C$,

so $x \in ( A \cap B ) \cup ( A \cap C)$

conversely if $x \in (A \cap B) \cup ( A \cap C)$ then $x \in A$ and $B$ or $x$ is in $A$ and $C$.

so $x$ is in $A$, and $x$ is in $B$ or $C$, ie $x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$

To me, it seems reasonable, I just don't know if I am making any jumps, I am basically just using the terms 'and' as well as 'or' to go between the equalities.

Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: It appears fine to me; some people might complain that something like the step from $x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$ to $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$ is a jump, but it's easily justified by considering the cases $x\in(A\cap B)$ and $x\in(A\cap C)$.